# Is it possible to unit test client side javascript without creating a global variable?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, client-side

I'm trying to write unit tests with jasmine for client side javascript.

Normally I wrap the client side javascript in an anonymous function like this

```
(function(){ 
            // my code
           })()
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't find a way to make this accessible to Jasmine. Is there a way for me to make "my code" available to jasmine for testing without doing something like this

```
var foo = function(){
                      //my code
                     }
foo()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want any outside code (not just Jasmine) to be able to use any part of what you've written, it will have to be global at some level. That does not mean that you have to expose every variable and function, but as with any software module, anything intended to be publicly available must be exposed.

For example, if you have the following code:

```
var purchaseAmount = 50;
var taxRate = 0.08;

function CalculateBill() {
    return purchaseAmount + ComputeTax();
}

function ComputeTax() {
    return purchaseAmount * taxRate;
}
```

Your first approach would hide all of this from being used anywhere else:

```
(function () {
    //Everything from the previous code sample

    alert(CalculateBill());
})();

//Jasmine has no access to CalculateBill()
```

What you could do is create a single class exposes only what should needs to be public:

```
function FinancialCalculator(taxRate) {
    function ComputeTax(purchaseAmount) {
        return purchaseAmount * taxRate;
    }

    this.CalculateBill = function(purchaseAmount) {
        return purchaseAmount + ComputeTax(purchaseAmount);
    }
}
```

And Jasmine could do something like this:

```
describe("Financial Calculator", function() {
    it("Calculates the bill correctly", function() {
        expect(new FinancialCalculator(0.08).CalculateBill(50)).toEqual(54);
    });
});
```

While `ComputeTax()` and the other underlying implementation details are still hidden.

If a class is not well-suited to your situation, you could instead use a single global object that similarly exposes exactly what is publicly needed. This is the approach taken by jQuery and Knockout.js with `$` and `ko`, respectively.